# Java and mysql database: using java swing

Tags: java, mysql

Hello i have a problem i am building a tool that looks like phpMyadmin interface in java but i can't get the right query that can prompt a user to create tables from the interface and then access the table in mysql database!
Someone please help me with this question!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So far, you haven't really formulated any question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database